# Doubly LinkedLists type Generic, can't get lastIndexOf() method to work

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator, doubly-linked-list, lastindexof

Ran into a slight problem of where for my DoublyLinkedList's `lastIndexOf(E element)` only returns -1. My code for `indexOf(E element)` works correctly though.

I'm using my `DoublyLinkedListIterator` to do the finding. The code for that is currently:

```
/**
 * Returns an element of type E
 */
@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator()  {
    return new DoublyLinkedListIterator();
}

/**
 * An Iterator Class for DoublyLinkedLists
 */
private class DoublyLinkedListIterator implements Iterator<E>{
    private Node current = node.next; // The node to be returned by next();
    private Node lastUsed = null; // The last node to be returned by either previous() or next()
                                  // This will be resetted when remove() is used or if add() is used.
    private int index = 0; // Keeps track of index for use in next() and previous(), add() and remove()

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index < numberOfElementsInList; // if index is less than the number of elements in the DoublyLinkedList, return true
    }

    public E next() {
        if(hasNext() == false){
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        lastUsed = current; // Makes the current node and remembers that it was last used 
                            // Remember, current is already 
        E data = current.data; // Adds the element in current node to E data
        current = current.next; // makes the next node after the current node, THE current node.
        index++;
        return data; // return that data
    }

    public boolean hasPrevious() {
        return index > 0; // if the index is greater than 0, then there is at least 1 element in the DoublyLinkedList. Return true if there is.
    }

    public E previous() {
        if(hasPrevious() == false){ 
            throw new NoSuchElementException(); // if hasPrevious() returns false (meaning if there is no previous node), will throw exception.
        }
        current = current.prev; // Takes the previous Node 
        index--;
        lastUsed = current; // Will set this Node to lastUsed, so that way if remove() or add() is used, it won't throw an exception.
        return current.data;
    }
```

And this is what I currently have for my indexOf() and lastIndexOf():

```
@Override
public int indexOf(E element) {
    DoublyLinkedListIterator indexOfIterator = new DoublyLinkedListIterator();
    int index = 0;

    while(indexOfIterator.hasNext()){
        if(indexOfIterator.next().equals(element)){
            return index;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return -1;
}

/**
 * Returns the index with this element of it's last occurrence.
 * Returns -1 if the element is not found.
 */
@Override
public int lastIndexOf(E element) {
    DoublyLinkedListIterator lastIndexIterator = new DoublyLinkedListIterator();
    int index = numberOfElementsInList;

    while(lastIndexIterator.hasPrevious()){
        if(lastIndexIterator.previous().equals(element)){
            return index;
        }
        index--;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The way that I'm checking it is by the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    DoublyLinkedList<Object> list = new DoublyLinkedList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        list.add(i, i+1);
    }
    list.add(8, 3);
    printArray(list.toArray());
    System.out.println("The number 2 shows up first first at index: " + list.indexOf(3));
    System.out.println("The number 2 shows up very last at index: " + list.lastIndexOf(3));
}
```

Which gives out the following results:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 3 9 10 
The number 2 shows up first first at index: 2
The number 2 shows up very last at index: -1
```

What am I doing wrong here? I figured it would be just like indexOf() but only a bit backwards by decrementing the index from it's size().

Comment: I don´t understand the difference between the two methods. Basicly both of them initialize the `DoublyLinkedListIterator` the same way, but have to act different(once incrementing, once decrementing). In my eyes there´s a problem, or maybe even the problem.

Comment: Where is `index` initialized in `previous()` with the max number of elements in the linked list? If you have missed it, this looks like the problem.